# make plotly use body font

Tags: css, r, plotly

I'm using R to generate a plotly plot and would like that plot to use the same font as the body of the HTML page on which it is shown without having to explicitly specify the body font. This, unfortunately, doesn't quite work:

```
layout(demo_plotly, font = list(family = 'inherit'))
```

Comment: is it possible to tell why it does not work? which error you get?

Comment: The font simply doesn't change. Which I'm guessing is because this doesn't inherit straight from body but from some other element instead?

Comment: do this and see if it works layout(demo_plotly, font = list(family = "Courier New, monospace")) it should be in ""

Comment: is you put the **family = "inherit"** it still does not work?

Comment: The line I posted does not do the trick. How does your line differ from mine?

Comment: if you look at it carefully, you see that I use " instead ' , and since R is case sensitive, it would be best to set it as manual of plotly says which use " and not '. However, it does not harm if you just try and see if this is the reason because I cannot think of anything else

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, unfortunately.

Comment: sorry to hear that, lets hope someone give a better idea. In the meantime i read about it and if I find something better, I will inform you. cheers